# How do I remove printer that is no longer used?

Tags: printing, ubuntu-mate, cups-lpd

The MG2220 printer is no longer connected to my computer.

Yet `lpstat` is still showing it.

How can I get that removed?

```
$ lpstat -p
printer Canon_TS9100_series is idle.  enabled since Mon 11 Mar 2019 04:41:26 PM CDT
printer HL-2240-series is idle.  enabled since Tue 12 Mar 2019 03:28:52 PM CDT
printer MG2200-series is idle.  enabled since Wed 20 Feb 2019 10:50:51 AM CST
```

Comment: Have you tried editing the `printers.conf` file? Usually located under `/etc/cups/`

Comment: @Sarriman Do I delete this and everything below it? </DefaultPrinter>
<Printer MG2200-series>

Comment: Those are `xml` formatted data. Be sure to remove the hole entry, or any other entry that you may like. If you are uncertain, create a backup file by `sudo cp printer.conf ./printers.conf.backup`, just in case something goes bad.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer when I opened CUPS in my browser.

Administration, Manage Printers, and Delete Printer.